# How to override what response [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] returns or validate the token manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

If I use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute for the API method I get autogenerated HTTP400 JSON. I want to be able to ovewrite JSON contents. Can I somehow manually decide what is being responded on validation issue?

I implemented my own:

```
public class ExceptionFilteraaAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context?.Exception != null)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(...)
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but it never gets to this place as already `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` responded to the request.

---

I needed to implement:

```
public class ChangedAntiforgeryResultFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
  
//this is never hit
    if (context?.Result is AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new LoginErrorResponseDto
        {
            OperationId = context.HttpContext.Features?.Get<RequestTelemetry>()?.Context?.Operation?.Id
        });
    }
}

public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
{
}
```

}

and added to my controller and my method has attributes:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ChangedAntiforgeryResultFilter]
```

my `ChangedAntiForgeryResultFilter` is never reached, the 400 is returned with defualt contents.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* build your own authorization filter by copying the default [`ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs), replacing the result it generates. An easier way, one that doesn’t require you to reimplement the validation logic, would be to add a result filter in addition to the default `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` that checks for the `AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult` and replaces it by something else. Such a filter could look as simple as this:

```cs
public class ChangedAntiforgeryResultFilter : IAlwaysRunResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    { }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[TypeFilter(typeof(ChangedAntiforgeryResultFilter))]
public IActionResult ExampleAction(ExampleModle model)
    => View(model);
```

That being said, I wouldn’t recommend changing the response code though.The [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) are very precisely defined. A 4xx error means that there is a *client* error while a 5xx error means that there is a *server* error. The client not sending the correct anti-forgery token is very much a client error. Returning a [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) in such a situation would be just wrong.

The default response from the `AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult` is a [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) which is the correct result here:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want change any codes, just want to return only `operationId` with any 4xx/5xx , but at the same time I don't want to alter any behaviour of other API controllers in the app.

Comment: I get error that `context.Result` is read only, it has only getter.

Comment: @Yoda Oops, my bad, you need to implement the `OnResultExecuting` method. I corrected my code

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my question, unfortunately this filter is never reached. I need to define filter only for this controller.

Comment: I switched to: `IAlwaysRunResultFilter` then it is executed, but
`context.Result.GetType()` returns `{Name = "ObjectResult" FullName = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult"}` so this `context.Result is AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult` is always false.

Comment: @Yoda Guess I was wrong and you cannot overwrite the result returned from an authorization filter :/ [_“Result filters are not executed when an authorization filter or resource filter short-circuits the pipeline.”_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iresultfilter-and-iasyncresultfilter). Sorry about that. Unfortunately, the `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` is internal, so you cannot just inherit from it but will need to roll your own then :/

Comment: Pleae have a look at my previous comment I switched to `IAlwaysRunResultFilter`.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that one. Let me try it out myself to see what goes on here.

Comment: @Yoda Updated my answer with the code that I was able to run this with successfully. Maybe your `ObjectResult` comes from somewhere else?

Comment: No matter if it is error caused by invalid model state or validation of the token it is always `ObjectResult` :(.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net transforms an error result (a result with status code 400 or higher) to a result with **ProblemDetails**. You can change this in various ways as described at [handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#client-error-response).

This works in ASP.NET 7 if `SuppressMapClientErrors` is set to `true`:

```cs
public class RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter : IAlwaysRunResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
            context.Result = new ObjectResult("XSRF failed") { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden };
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add<RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>();
    })
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
    });
```